# Outputting an element when a clicked element's id equals object element

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to display the appropriate input for the correct icon displayed. I structured all of my elements as an object and created the key to match the id of the matching icon. I then created the element to the appropriate input to match.

My issue is, when I click on the icon, nothing outputs. I do not get any errors, my `console.log` is showing me the looped results.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? If you click on the blue Zillow icon, then the input with the placeholder "Zillow" should appear. The same thing with the Realtor one, except it be associated with the Realtor input/icon.

```js
var reviewInputs = {
  "zillow-review": '<input type="url" id="zillow-input" placeholder="Zillow">',
  "realtor-review": '<input type="url" id="realtor-input" placeholder="Realtor">'
};

$('.review-icon-select').click(function() {
  $('#review-site-edit-wrap').addClass('active');
  var reviewIconClicked = $(this).attr('id');

  $.each(reviewInputs, function(key, element) {
    console.log('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + element);
    if (reviewIconClicked == reviewInputs) {
      reviewInputs.forEach(function(site) {
        $('#review-site-edit').append.reviewInputs[element];
      });
    }
  });

  //$(reviewIconClicked':contains("SomeText")').each(function () {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="review-icon-select" id="zillow-review"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/retain-static/www/zillow.jpg" alt="Zillow"></li>
<li class="review-icon-select" id="realtor-review"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/retain-static/www/realtor.com.png" alt="Realtor.com"></li>
<div id="review-site-edit"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check if the id of the clicked element is a property of your object.

No loop needed.

```js
var reviewInputs = {
  "zillow-review": '<input type="url" id="zillow-input" placeholder="Zillow">',
  "realtor-review": '<input type="url" id="realtor-input" placeholder="Realtor">'
};

$('.review-icon-select').click(function() {
  //$('#review-site-edit-wrap').addClass('active');  // Maybe used...
  var reviewIconClicked = $(this).attr('id');
  
  if(reviewInputs.hasOwnProperty(reviewIconClicked)){
    $('#review-site-edit').find("input[type='url']").remove();
    $('#review-site-edit').append(reviewInputs[reviewIconClicked]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="review-icon-select" id="zillow-review"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/retain-static/www/zillow.jpg" alt="Zillow"></li>
<li class="review-icon-select" id="realtor-review"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/retain-static/www/realtor.com.png" alt="Realtor.com"></li>
<div id="review-site-edit"></div>
```

Comment: It isn't doing the same as in the snippet ?

Comment: What do you mean by *«added to the DOM»* ?

Comment: Is it that you want only ONE input... So the previous should be removed ?

Comment: Any other way besides the `empty()` method? That is wiping out my submit button.

Comment: Perfect... I appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

```
if (reviewIconClicked == reviewInputs) {
```

try

```
reviewInputs['reviewIconClicked']
```